# How to use specify data types in curried function?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm trying to make a curried function in SMLNJ that appends a (string * bool) pair to a list. I could do this:

```
fun push L a b = (a,b) :: L;
-val push = fn : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b) list
```

That works, but I want a function that only accepts a (string * bool) list, string, and bool. I can't figure out how to write the function signature.

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to add an explicit type annotation in the function definition:

```
fun push L a b = (a:string,b:bool) :: L;
```

The inferred type is

```
val push = fn : (string * bool) list -> string -> bool -> (string * bool) list
```

Having said that -- I am not a big fan of needlessly making polymorphic functions less polymorphic. Rigid type checking doesn't need to be on the level of utility functions.